# Disable or remove the print menu item in a SwiftUI macOS app

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

How can I disable or remove a menu item in a SwiftUI macOS app? For example, the `Print...` item is shown in the `File` menu by default. But my application does not use printing features. How would I remove the print item from the file menu in a SwiftUI Mac app?

[image: swiftui print menu item]

I tried the following in `AppDelegate.swift` but it doesn't work:

```swift
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    
    func applicationWillFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let menu = NSApplication.shared.mainMenu {
            menu.item(withTitle: "File")?.submenu?.item(withTitle: "Print...")?.state = NSControl.StateValue.off
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: What kind of app did you generate? I've created using templates for default and document based Apps and none of both have by default Print item in File menu.

Comment: @Asperi I created the app with an early version of SwiftUI that uses an AppDelegate.swift file.

Comment: I already don't remember, not sure, but seems early project templates had main menu nib/xib. If you can find one in your project then just remove menu item from there.

Comment: @Asperi Ah yes, I see the Main.storyboard. I removed Print... from the File menu using the storyboard. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Asperi You should type that up into an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[per-request @Alexander]

Early SwiftUI project templates had explicit resource for main menu, `Main.storyboard` (or xib file). If you can find one in your project then just locate menu there and remove Print menu item manually.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you would remove default menu items in a modern SwiftUI app that doesn't have a storyboard?